# How to make a mac detect all plugged-in devices? (via USB or otherwise)

Tags: display, usb, sleep-wake

I have an M1 macbook running Big Sur.

A monitor and a keyboard are plugged-in via a USB-C dongle.

When the laptop goes to sleep, it forgets about the connected devices. After waking it up with keystrokes on the laptop (not the plugged-in keyboard, because it doesn't work), I have to unplug and replug the dongle for it to detect the devices. Usually, I have to restart the monitor too.

I'm wondering if there is a way to ask a mac to check for connected devices without physically touching any cables?

Maybe sending a "wake signal" to the connected devices, too?

Comment: Is the Mac connected to a charger?

Comment: Yes, through the dongle.

Comment: I'd say that's unusual or unexpected. First thing is to test the cheapest bit: do they work with a different dongle?

Comment: Are all dongles drawing power from the Mac?  Nothing plugged into AC power, or having pass through power from a power brick?  I don't know if that matters but I do recall different sleep behavior from a USB-C drive from when plugged in directly and when plugged into a dock.

Comment: The charger does go through my dongle.  I'll try to see if the behavior is different when not using the dongle for charging.

Comment: Correction on my earlier comment... Should have been, "Are *any* dongles drawing power from Mac?"  I missed comment on dock getting AC power but was confused about singular "dongle" but plural "devices".  I thought this meant more than one USB-C dongle.  Ignore previous question and apologies for my reading comprehension.  Perhaps not important, what are all devices?  Keyboard. Video. Mouse?  SD slot?  I'm thinking dock is confused, not Mac.  I agree with @benwiggy to try different dock if possible.  I was able to find a nice dock for $40, which is not horrible if it fixes the problem.